# How to make footer have fixed position

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my footer fixed, while still using clip-path on the divs above. I want the footer to become more visible the further you scroll down, beneath the middle div.

I have tried doing bottom: 0, and various other floats while the position is set to fixed. When the position is not defined, or set to relative, the footer is placed at the bottom of the page, as usual.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Torsken/pen/OZKWvJ

Here is the code I have so far;

```
<body>
  <div class="background_top">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="background_middle_1">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="background_middle_2">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>

</body>
<footer>
  <div class="footer">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
</footer>

.background_top {
  background-color: #232323;
  height: 70vh;
  width: 100vw;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 40%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 96%, 0 100%);
  z-index: -200;
}

.background_middle_1 {
  background-color: green;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 100vw;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 80% , 100% 80%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 96%, 0 100%);
  z-index: -220;
  margin-top: -45vh;
}

.background_middle_2 {
  background-color: green;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 100vw;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 70%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 96%, 0 100%);
  z-index: -220;
}

footer {
  margin: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: -230;
}

.footer {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50vh;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have width specified inside of footer class. By adding

width: 100% will fix the issue.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.background_top {
  background-color: #232323;
  height: 70vh;
  width: 100vw;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 40%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 96%, 0 100%);
  z-index: -200;
}

.background_middle_1 {
  background-color: green;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 100vw;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 80% , 100% 80%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 96%, 0 100%);
  z-index: -220;
  margin-top: -45vh;
}

.background_middle_2 {
  background-color: green;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 100vw;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 70%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 96%, 0 100%);
  z-index: -220;
}

.footer {
  margin: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: -230;
  width: 100%; /* your code over here*/
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50vh;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="background_top">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="background_middle_1">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="background_middle_2">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>

</body>

<footer>

  <div class="footer">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>

</footer>
```

Comment: Yes it does seem like you fixed it! It should look something like this footer: http://presse.no

Do you know if there is any way I could make the footer have more height on the left side of the screen?

Comment: That's great! All I did was add the width: 100%; to the .footer and also added dot(.) to the footer, so ".footer" But the right way is to put everything inside of one .footer class, instead of two separate and same class, unless it's .footer:after and :before

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I´ll try to experiment, to get the footer to look more like on " presse.no ", so that the content above keeps scrolling but the footer stays put.

Comment: Yes, I think you can. Maybe try adding to the, * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
   min-height: 200px;(this kind of does the trick)
}

Comment: It totally does, thanks! I´ll also try finding how to make my divs not have white space when srolling to left or right (on mac), and an easy way of storing content in the footer. You have been to much help, thanks a lot!

Comment: You are very welcome! For the footer you can always make "height: 60vh;" This will hide the white space on the footer part. But if you will add content to footer, you should margin-top, and see how much you need to drop it down. Because your other div will cover the footer. Hope it help. Good luck 